# define and assign function call result in racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I would like to assign the result of a function call (a list) to some var/name.
I tried

```
(define somelist (call-a-function arg))
```

but when I do

```
(display somelist)
```

it prints `#procedure`

What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: Are you *sure* `(call-a-function arg)` yields a list? What happens when you evaluate that directly in the REPL?

Answer (score 4):

It's a safe bet that this:

```
(call-a-function arg)
```

Is returning a *function*, not a list as you assumed. That's why you're getting a `#procedure` printed on-screen. Check your function, make sure it returns the appropriate value.